# Split an array with a regular expression

Tags: php, regex, arrays

I'm wondering if it is possible to truncate an array by using a regular expression.

In particular I have an array like this one:

```
$array = array("AaBa","AaBb","AaBc","AaCa","AaCb","AaCc","AaDa"...);
```

I have this string:

```
$str = "AC";
```

I'd like the slice of `$array` from the start to the last occurrence of a string matching `/A.C./` (in the sample, "AaCc" at index 5):

```
$result = array("AaBa","AaBb","AaBc","AaCa","AaCb","AaCc");
```

How can I do this? I thought I might use `array_slice`, but I don't know how to use a RegEx with it.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you want. Your pattern description seems more a `fnmatch()` glob. And then it is ambiguous if you just want the list filtered, or extract a consecutive range of matches.

Comment: `/A*C*/i` would also match an empty string. Are you quite sure you should be using regular expressions for this task?

Comment: What, exactly, is the relationship between `$str` and the pattern supposed to be?

Comment: Sorry I've updated the question I ment "/A.C./"
A followed by only 1 random character followed by C followed by only 1 random character.

Comment: @Giorgio: I made an update to the code in the original version (so make sure to use that) and posted an alternate version if you're interested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's [my bid](http://ideone.com/j8COs)

```
function split_by_contents($ary, $pattern){
  if (!is_array($ary)) return FALSE; // brief error checking

  // keep track of the last position we had a match, and the current
  // position we're searching
  $last = -1; $c = 0;

  // iterate over the array
  foreach ($ary as $k => $v){
    // check for a pattern match
    if (preg_match($pattern, $v)){
      // we found a match, record it
      $last = $c;
    }
    // increment place holder
    $c++;
  }

  // if we found a match, return up until the last match
  // if we didn't find one, return what was passed in
  return $last != -1 ? array_slice($ary, 0, $last + 1) : $ary;
}
```

---

### Update

My original answer has a `$limit` argument that served no purpose. I did originally have a different direction I was going to go with the solution, but decided to keep it simple. However, below is the [version that implements that `$limit`](http://ideone.com/YTO5R). So...

```
function split_by_contents($ary, $pattern, $limit = 0){
  // really simple error checking
  if (!is_array($ary)) return FALSE;

  // track the location of the last match, the index of the
  // element we're on, and how many matches we have found
  $last = -1; $c = 0; $matches = 0;

  // iterate over all items (use foreach to keep key integrity)
  foreach ($ary as $k => $v){

    // text for a pattern match
    if (preg_match($pattern, $v)){

      // record the last position of a match
      $last = $c;

      // if there is a specified limit, capture up until
      // $limit number of matches, then exit the loop
      // and return what we have
      if ($limit > 0 && ++$matches == $limit){
        break;
      }
    }

    // increment position counter
    $c++;
  }
```

Comment: It could be a little more efficient to use something like `for($key = sizeof($array)-1; $key>=0; $key--)` - start from the tail end of the array, and then just return on the first match.

Comment: @SpoonNZ: Though about it, but I'm not sure what kind of array will be passed. For something where the keys don't matter, sure. But if they ever passed `array('aa' => 'AaAa', 'ab' => 'AaBb', 'ac' => 'AaCc');` it would stink.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way might be with a foreach loop, then using a regex against each value - happy to be proven wrong though!

One alternative could be to implode the array first...

```
$array = array("AaBa","AaBb","AaBc","AaCa","AaCb","AaCc","AaDa"...);
$string = implode('~~',$array);
//Some regex to split the string up as you want, guessing something like
// '!~~A.C.~~!' will match just what you want?
$result = explode('~~',$string);
```

If you'd like a hand with the regex I can do, just not 100% on exactly what you're asking - the `"A*C*"-->"AaCc"` bit I'm not too sure on?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming incremental numeric indices starting from 0

```
$array = array("AaBa","AaBb","AaBc","AaCa","AaCb","AaCc","AaDa");
$str = "AC";

$regexpSearch = '/^'.implode('.',str_split($str)).'.$/';
$slicedArray = array_slice($array,
                           0,
                           array_pop(array_keys(array_filter($array,
                                                             function($entry) use ($regexpSearch) { 
                                                                 return preg_match($regexpSearch,$entry); 
                                                             }    
                                                            )
                                               )
                                    )+1
                          );

var_dump($slicedArray);
```

PHP >= 5.3.0 and will give a

> Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference

And if no match is found, will still return the first element.